# Missing required parameter on form action

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

First of all, I would like to say that my English is not so good and is my first time posting here, so excuse me if I did something wrong! Well, I am starting practicing with Laravel and I am trying to create a URL for users can like posts. my URL and controller is right now this `Route::post('/post/{post}/like', [LikeController::class, 'postLike'])->name('post.like');` where post is the posts id that i am trying to pass through my form action attribute. Here is my form:

```html
@props(['id'])

<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'card-footer d-flex justify-content-around']) }}>
    <form action= "{{ route('post.like' , $id) }}"  method="post" >
        @csrf
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

If you wonder if the `id` is not actually passed into the component, I checked `{{ dd($id) }}` and it printed it.

My controller is this which it doesn't actually do anything right now. I am just trying to pass the id:

```php
class LikeController extends Controller
{
    public function postLike(Post $post) {
        dd($post);
    }
}
```

After all this i am getting the error:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: post.like] [URI: post/{id}/like] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: blog\resources\views\components\post\interaction.blade.php)

I am having two days to find the problem and I am still trying this moment I am sending this... I can't found where is the mistake! If you could help me would be much appreciated! Ty in advance

Comment: This is unbelievable!! i really cant find any reason this doesnt work !!!

Comment: It working only if i hard coded the url like this : ```<form action="/post/{{$id}}/like" method="POST">``` I am realy confuses why it doesnt work with the route helper.... it should !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Also, jesus its working if i do something like ```<form action="{{ route('post.like' , 2) }}" method="POST">``` by giving the integer id of the post without a parameter!!! So this works: ```<form action="{{ route('post.like' , 2) }}" method="POST">``` and this not:```<form action="{{ route('post.like' , $id) }}" method="POST">``` What the... is going on here!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the ID as an associative array in your [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route).

```
{{ route('post.like', ['id' => $id]) }}
```

Comment: Hello! i forgot to mention that i already tried that! but it doesnt work either! Btw I think if u have to pass only one parameter in your route u can avoid associative array :) Thx for ur time sir

Answer (score 2):

If the named route defines parameters, you may pass the parameters as the second argument to the route function. The given parameters will automatically be inserted into the generated URL in their correct positions and you should name 'post' instead of 'id':

```
Route::post('/post/{post}/like', [LikeController::class, 'postLike'])->name('post.like');
```

And you can call this route anywhere

```
route('post.like', [$postId])
```

If that still doesn't work for you. Then it might be issue of Route Cache Run:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Hello ! As i mention to mr  @Arjun bhati i changed my route to ```Route::post('/post/{post}/like', [LikeController::class, 'postLike'])->name('post.like');``` and still same error! Also i have clear my route cache many times! Didnt change nothing

Comment: Can you please confirm that this issue exist with other routes as well?

Comment: Yea i have a route ```Route::post('/post/{post}', [LikeController::class, 'postShow'])->name('post.show');``` and also getting the same error Missing required parameter for [Route: post.show] [URI: post/{post}] [Missing parameter: post].

Comment: Is there any bug because i am calling a route inside a component??? I can find any mistake here really!!! And it just a simple parameter pass!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Use same name parameter**

> When you use "id" keyword as a parameter in web.php then also same name pass in function argument in the controller

```
Route::post('/post/{id}/like', [LikeController::class, 'postLike'])->name('post.like');
```

> Controller

```
class LikeController extends Controller
    {
        public function postLike(Post $id) {
        dd($id);
        }
    }
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Hello! I have changed it to ```Route::post('/post/{post}/like', [LikeController::class, 'postLike'])->name('post.like');``` and still dosnt work!!! Still same error!!!!

Comment: Same name use both place like when you use post in route then also $post use in controller

Comment: Its the same name buddy , i have no idea why it prints me an error!!!

Comment: Bro checks your $id variable. It has any value or not.  Maybe your id variable is null.

Comment: Have printed it and it outouts the id so thats not the problem!!! I think maybe its a bug!

Comment: Try create route laravel 7 version Route::get('/post/{id}/like', 'LikeController@postLike')->name('post.like');

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea this could be the problem but after many changes i cast the id of the post into an integer and it actually worked `<form action= "{{ route('post.like' , (int)$id) }}"  method="post" >` . I don't know why i should cast the id into an integer because its already an integer by default and i checked that with `{{ dd(getType($id)) }}` and printed "integer"! I am really confused but it works! But i am not happy because i have no idea why i should cast an integer into an integer to make it work! Doesn't make any sense! If anyone has an answer to this would be great!